# Xcode deployment target

Tags: iphone, deployment, xcode4

If my deployment target is set to iOS 4.1 and submitted to apple, and they test the app on iOS 4.3, would that cause the app to malfunction? My app was rejected for a bug that I am unable to recreate on my iPhone 4. The exact same device model they tested the app on. I simply cannot find the bug or error in my code.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like your problem doesn't have to do with deployment targets specifically; you will have better luck if you delete this question and ask another about how to reproduce the specific behavior Apple found. (You can also write back to Apple, they do reply.)

Comment: **What version of iOS is installed on your phone?**

Answer (score 0):

If you build your app to target iOS 4.1 it should run on iOS 4.3. It's possible that your app does something that works on 4.1 but causes a problem on 4.3; I had that myself with an app already in the store, and had to post an update so it worked correctly under a newer iOS release.

**Note that you can tell the iOS Simulator what version iOS to simulate:** on the Hardware menu, select Version, and subsequent runs will be tested against that version of the system libraries.

The simulator is not a perfect reproduction of a real device, but hopefully you can do this to reproduce the behavior that Apple has seen on their devices.

Comment: Cheers for your reply. I am unable to use the simulator for it because it uses the ipod library. However I have updated the deployment target to 4.3 and uploaded the app onto my iphone 4 and it works fine. Just like the 4.1 targeted app. =( I cant reproduce the problem apple are having.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test it on your iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3? There's two parts to the puzzle. If they rejected it for crashing under iPhone 4, you have to check all the different iOS versions you claim to support. The target iOS 4.1 should still make it work on 4.3, you just might have a crash (which apparently you do). Through testing with that actual software version on your iPhone, you'll find the bug and hopefully squash it. Good luck!